# How can I get x,y,z values of iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.Vector object?

Tags: c#, class, itext

How can I get x,y,z values of `iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.Vector` object?
These are non-public members.

[image]

Comment: Long shot, but could you sure your `LocationTextExtractionStrategyEx` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the source, yes you can.

```
/**
 * Gets the value from a coordinate of the vector
 * @param index the index of the value to get (I1, I2 or I3)
 * @return a coordinate value
 */
public float this[int index] {
    get {
        return vals[index];
    }
}
```

You can access them by their index:

```
var x = v[0];
var y = v[1];
var z = v[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Vector`](http://opensourcejavaphp.net/csharp/itextsharp/Vector.cs.html) contains an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx):

```
public float this[int index] {
    get {
        return vals[index];
    }
}
```

So you'll be able to access them through `v[n]`.